# FTP Client Output Behavior

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am using a batch file to download and upload a FTP file to measure thoughput. The odd part is when I capture the ftp output to text file the values get jumbled or miss placed. Note the first two and last two lines. Is this a bug within Windows? Below is an example:

```
>ftp: 1048576 bytes received in Seconds Kbytes/sec.  
ftp> 1.75597.82put 1mb  
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.  
150 Ok to send data.  
226 File receive OK.  
ftp: 1048576 bytes sent in Seconds Kbytes/sec.  
ftp> 2.44430.27bye
```

It should look like this:

> ftp: 1048576 bytes received in 1.74Seconds 604.37Kbytes/sec.
>       ftp> put 1mb
>       200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
>       150 Ok to send data.
>       226 File receive OK.
>       ftp: 1048576 bytes sent in 2.24Seconds 468.53Kbytes/sec.
>       ftp> bye

The Batch File is:

> @echo off
>       systeminfo > %userName%.txt
>       netstat -a -n >> %userName%.txt
>       netstat -S >> %userName%.txt
>       ftp -n -s:ftp.txt >> %userName%.txt
>       netstat -S >> %userName%.txt
>       del 1mb

And the ftp.txt is:

> `open ftp.XXX.com
>
>       user
>
>       ftp
>
>       ftp
>
>       bin
>
>       cd /incoming
>
>       get 1mb
>
>       put 1mb
>
>       bye`

Comment: When asking for help with your batch file... **Show your batch file.**

Comment: I see the same garbled output (Windows 7) when I redirect ftp.exe output to a file.  Can't explain why.

Comment: I should have said this is using Windows 7. I tried it in Windows XP and it worked fine.

Comment: Try redirecting stderr to your text file also by adding `2>&1` to the end of your ftp command which will make it `ftp -n -s:ftp.txt >> %userName%.txt 2>&1`

Comment: This is a bug in Windows 7 ftp executable. I have since replaced ftp.exe with the version found in Windows XP.